# Do you go through immigration when transiting through Australia?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, transit, syd

I (US citizen) will be traveling from New Zealand to the United States via Australia on Qantas. There is a plane change and a 3-hour layover in Sydney. Do I need to go through Australian immigration? I will have an Australian visa as the first part of the trip is in Australia.

Comment: Travelling Wellington-Sydney-London on a Qantas ticket throughout the airline transferred my baggage and I waited in the transit lounge. That was a couple of years ago. You won't need to go through customs, but it's possible that US security requirements may require you to re-screen your luggage.

Answer (score 7):

No, you do not clear customs in Australia in a NZ-Australia-US trip.  You will spend the 3 hour layover in the Sydney transit lounge (they have a decent selection of dining and shopping options).

You will most likely still go through security for yourself and carry-on items before re-boarding the flight, but you will not need to clear customs, declare items, or claim and re-check your checked baggage.